# Spring Boot Security: Deprecated commands

Tags: spring-boot, undefined, builder, spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-security

this is my code and in order to avoid WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I used **SecuirtyFilterChain and UserDetailsService.** Now I'm getting an error for the *User.Builder()* that can not be defined **"The method builder() is undefined for the type User"**. I have checked many youtube videos and i even downloaded Lombok but not of it were useful.

```
package com.configuration;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.model.User;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
      @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "removal" })
      @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
      }
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
        .username("user")
        .password("pass")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
  }



}
```

I could not extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter so in that case i start using SecuirtyFilterChain and UserDetailsService since it was announced over spring boot website that can be a good alternative but no matter what i try it will still give errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try using `withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` instead of `builder()`. and you must add the @EnableWebSecurity annotation to enable the web securities defined by [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your `.httpBasic()` add next one param something like this `.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())`

SecurityFilterChain will look so, nothing hard:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
          .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
      http
          .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
          http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
            request.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll();
            request.anyRequest().authenticated();
              });
          http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
      return http.build();
    }
```

And also you should to have a look here [Migration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html)